# Close button does not work jquery in one function

Tags: jquery, function, modal-dialog

Close button does not work jquery in one function

I have the following modal done in jquery, I tried several ways to solve the problems of the click on the close button, but I can not get it to work.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions?

LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/wx0wvh9L/

**JQUERY:**

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.modalBox = function($custom) {
    var name = "box-modal",
      custom = ($custom == null) ? "" : $custom;

    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var link = $(this).data("modal"),
        iframe = '<div class="' + name + ' ' + custom + '">' +
        '<iframe src="' + link + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' +
        '<div class="close"></div>' +
        '</div>';
      $("body").append(iframe);
      $("." + name).fadeIn(350);
    });

    $(".close").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("." + name).hide();
    });
  };
}(jQuery));

$(".modal-video").modalBox();
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-video" data-modal="https://www.youtube.com/embed/P2x3-b6JEj8?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1">
  Test Click
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead

```
$("body").on('click','.box-modal .close', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $("." + name).hide();
});
```

The problem you have is that `$('.close')` doesn't exist when you define it.  It only "exists" after you click.  You can also put it inside of the onclick method as an alternative.  This is due to the scopes in Javascript...

Like I said, you can also put it inside of the onclick method like so

```
$(this).on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var link = $(this).data("modal"),
        iframe = '<div class="' + name + ' ' + custom + '">' +
        '<iframe src="' + link + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' +
        '<div class="close"></div>' +
        '</div>';
      $("body").append(iframe);
      $("." + name).fadeIn(350);
      $(".close").on('click', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $("." + name).hide();
      });
    });
```